# Hibernate/persistence and singleton pattern

Tags: java, hibernate, singleton, persistence

I have a singleton that is to be persisted in database. Other persisted entities should have reference to this singleton. How can it be achieved with Hibernate?

I ended with something not-yet-working like this, faking the single ID of the singleton:

```
@Entity
@Subselect("select '1' as ID")
class Singleton {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long getId() { return 1l; }
    private void setId(Long id) { }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="ENT")
class MyEnt {
    // TODO: how to annotate so that table ENT doesn't need foreign key column 
   Singleton s;
}
```

The problem is that I don't want to have a column with foreign key in entities referencing the Singleton - because the singleton is only one and we don't need its ID...

Maybe I am thinking in a wrong way? Maybe it is wrong architecture issue? Did you solve similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

I ended with this:

```
@Entity
@Subselect("select '1' as ID, * from TABLE")
class Singleton {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long getId() { return 1l; }
    private void setId(Long id) { }
    // ... other useful fields persisted in TABLE
}

@Entity
@Table(name="ENT")
class MyEnt implements Lifecycle {
   Singleton s;
   void onLoad(Session sess, Serializable id) {
      this.s = sess.get(Singleton.class, 1l);
   }
   // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Singleton` is only one object, why do you want to map it in other entities?

You may want to load `Singleton` once and put it in `application context`. In that case, you may reuse it whenever you need it.

Comment: Yes but what if you need to restart the container or you have many containers? How to save the current state of the singleton? Or change it in all containers?

Comment: I meant have that object in the way designed. All I am trying so say that I don't see any reason of mapping this in other entities. Load the object once and keep in the app context. If you happen to restart the container, load it again.

Comment: 1. Because the data can change in database (webapp is on more nodes) 2. because the entity needs the singleton in its business logic methods. And I don't want to put it in it "manually". It could be done by the DAO service for entities loaded by this DAO service, but what to do with entities, that are loaded indirectly (referenced by the original entity)?

Comment: Also, my question didn't mention that Spring is used together. Although true, it would be nice to come with more general solution to the problem.

Comment: @Jakub By Application context, I don't mean spring application context, but I meant object like [Tomcat Application Context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationContext.html).