# Example of state data persisting across runs of Spring Boot Server

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to persist a variable state across my Spring Boot server starting and stopping.  For example, an integer representing where the server is in a queue of served objects that increments once per day (see "nowServing" below):

```
@RestController
public class ArticleController {

    @Autowired
    ArticleRepository articleRepo;

    // TODO - these two variables need to persist between runnings of the server.  Refactor to be set and get from the database.
    //the article with id '0' and '1' better be approved!
    private Integer nowServing = 0;          //where in the queue we are serving an article from at the moment
    LocalDate serveDate = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1);   //a date associated with the current article being served
    
    /**
     * When the date changes, find the next approved article in the queue, and set that as our serving point.
     * @return which primary key in our sorted table we're serving
     */
    private Integer nowServing() {
        if (!LocalDate.now().equals(serveDate)) {
            //time to start serving the next article
            serveDate = LocalDate.now();
            Boolean foundAnApprovedOne = false;
            for (nowServing++; ( (nowServing<articleRepo.count()) && (foundAnApprovedOne == false) ); nowServing++) {
                Optional<Article> article = articleRepo.findById(nowServing);
                if ( (article.isPresent()) && (article.get().getApprovalStatus()) ) {
                    foundAnApprovedOne = true;
                }
            }
            if (foundAnApprovedOne == false) {
                //There are no more approved articles left in the queue.  Restart from the beginning
                nowServing = 1;
            }
        }
        return nowServing;
    }
```

I've searched on how to persist state info, coming across such likely posts such as:
[JPA: Singleton Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053760/jpa-singleton-entity)
[Hibernate/persistence and singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937775/hibernate-persistence-and-singleton-pattern)

I think each example is only showing part of the whole, expecting the viewer to know how to integrate what's provided with other supplementary components.  My Spring competence is very limited right now, and I'm hoping to examine a more all-inclusive (repository, entity, controller, etc.) simple example I can adapt and learn from. Preferably, this example would stay away from beans and include an entity, to lean on my current strengths.

Comment: You could use a simple in-memory key-value database like Redis which would be more efficient I think. There is a Spring Data Redis Spring Boot starter which is very simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate Yann39's pointer to Redis, that's probably a superior way to do this work.  However, my limited Spring experience again got in the way of deciphering the Redis documentation.  I have built something out of the entity-repository-controller model I know:

Entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class StateData {

    //This class helps keep track of server data across instances of the the server running
    //There's a trade-off in this implementation:  consolidated gateway in the code, for
    //a database table that is going to have multiple unused(null) fields per instance.
        
    public static final int NOW_SERVING = 0;    //used to track where we are in the article queue
    public static final int SERVE_DATE  = 1;    //used to track what date the currently served article is associated with
    
    @Id
    private Integer variableName;

    //While multiple types are listed, each instance of StateData only uses one.
    //Think of this as a list of possibilities
    private Integer intValue;
    private LocalDate dateValue;

    public StateData() {}

    //To differentiate the StateData instance by type of variable (String, Integer, etc.), different constructors are used.
    public StateData(Integer id, Integer value) {
        setVariableName(id);
        setIntValue(value);
    }

    public StateData(Integer id, LocalDate value) {
        setVariableName(id);
        setDateValue(value);
    }

    public String getVariableName() {
        switch (variableName.intValue()) {
            case NOW_SERVING:
                return "nowServing";
            case SERVE_DATE:
                return "serveDate";
        }
        return "unknown";
    }
    
    /*
     * Pass in one of the static variable values defined above, such as NOW_SERVING
     */
    public void setVariableName(Integer variableName) {
        this.variableName = variableName;
    }
    
    //It's up to the programmer to know which get is appropriate for a particular StateData.
    //Calling getIntValue() on a StateData representing LocalDate, for example, is a useless op that returns null 
    
    public void setIntValue(Integer value) {
        this.intValue = value;
    }

    public Integer getIntValue() {
        return intValue;
    }

    public void setDateValue(LocalDate value) {
        this.dateValue = value;
    }

    public LocalDate getDateValue() {
        return dateValue;
    }

}
```

Repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.lotterysim.server.model.StateData;

public interface StateDataRepository extends CrudRepository<StateData, Integer> {

}
```

Controller:

public class ArticleController {

```
@Autowired
ArticleRepository articleRepo;

@Autowired
StateDataRepository stateDataRepo;      //used to persist server values across runnings of the server

private Integer nowServing = null;       //where in the queue we are serving an article from at the moment

LocalDate serveDate = null;   //a date associated with the current article being served

/**
 * Write state data for nowServing to database for persistent storage across server runnings
 * @param value  where in the queue we are in article servings
 */
private void setNowServing(int value) {
    nowServing = value;
    StateData sd = new StateData(StateData.NOW_SERVING, value);
    stateDataRepo.save(sd);
}

/**
 * Write state data for serveDate to database for persistent storage across server runnings
 * @param value  what day our serving is associated with
 */
private void setServeDate(LocalDate value) {
    serveDate= value;
    StateData sd = new StateData(StateData.SERVE_DATE, value);
    stateDataRepo.save(sd);
}

/**
 * When the date changes, find the next approved article in the queue, and set that as our serving point.
 * @param override force the queue to advance, even if the day hasn't 
 * @return which primary key in our sorted table we're serving
 */
private Integer nowServing(boolean override) {
    if (nowServing == null) {       //load state from database
        Optional<StateData> sdPhantom = stateDataRepo.findById(StateData.NOW_SERVING);
        if (sdPhantom.isPresent()) {
            nowServing = sdPhantom.get().getIntValue();
        } else {
            setNowServing(0);       //default
        }
    }

    if(serveDate == null) {         //load state from database
        Optional<StateData> sdPhantom = stateDataRepo.findById(StateData.SERVE_DATE);
        if (sdPhantom.isPresent()) {
            serveDate = sdPhantom.get().getDateValue();
        } else {
            setServeDate(LocalDate.now().minusDays(1));     //default.  Will trip a re-assessment
        }
    }
```

Treat this as psuedo-code, as I haven't confirmed it works as-is